# SwipeRefershLayout is not working in Android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

SwipeRefershLayout is not working in Android.

This is my XML code:

```
//other code
.....

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchCardView">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/room_dashboard_sample"/>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
.....
//other codes
```

This is My MainActivity:

```
        modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    dashboardAdapter = new DashboardAdapter(this, modelList);
    binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(dashboardAdapter);

    modelList.clear();
    firestore.collection("Rooms").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
        List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
        for (DocumentSnapshot d : list) {
            DashboardModel obj = d.toObject(DashboardModel.class);
            modelList.add(obj);
        }
        dashboardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Timber.d("onFailure: %s", e.getMessage()));

    //please give attension in this below code!
    binding.swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
        dashboardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        binding.swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    });
```

Comment: You have to call database again if you want to update the list

Comment: Why is your `RecyclerView` width and Height is set to 0dp ? `SwipeRefreshLayout` not a child of Contraitslayout . Change it to match_parent .

Comment: ok @ADM ..........................

Comment: You get that behavior, most likely because both width and height are 0dp, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better you create a specific method to call the database. You can wrap them up inside a method.

```
private void getRoomsList(){
    firestore.collection("Rooms").orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
        List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
        for (DocumentSnapshot d : list) {
            DashboardModel obj = d.toObject(DashboardModel.class);
            modelList.add(obj);
        }
        dashboardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Timber.d("onFailure: %s", e.getMessage()));
}
```

Then, you just need to call it inside `onCreate` and `swipeRefreshLayout`.

```
binding.swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
    getRoomList();
    binding.swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
});
```

For better approach, you can call the `setRefreshing` after the `notifyDataSetChanged` and remove it from below `getRoomList` like below:

```
//another code...
dashboardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
binding.swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); //place it here
```

While at the `swipeRefreshLayout`.

```
binding.swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
    getRoomList();
});
```